# Find $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\cdot2^{n-k}\cdot\binom{n }{k}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, summation, binomial-coefficients

Find

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\cdot2^{n-k}\cdot\binom{n  }{k}}$$

**My attemt:** By the binomia theorem, we have
$$(1-x)^n={\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n  }{k} (-1)^k x^k} $$
from here how can I manipulate this to get the limit?

Comment: Consider $ [\int ] ( 2 - x) ^{ n}$

Comment: $$\frac1{k+1}\binom nk=\frac1{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}.$$

Comment: Thomas Andrews, thanks I edit it

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}2^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}
&= \frac{2^n}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\binom{n+1}{k+1} \\
&= \frac{2^n}{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}\binom{n+1}{k} \\
&= \frac{-2^{n+1}}{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\binom{n+1}{k} \\
&= \frac{-2^{n+1}}{n+1} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\binom{n+1}{k} - 1\right) \\
&= \frac{-2^{n+1}}{n+1} \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1} - 1\right) \\
&= \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
    ( 2 - x) ^{ n}
    = \sum_{ k = 0}^{ n} \binom{ n}{ k} ( -1) ^{ k} x^{ k} 2^{ n - k}
.\end{aligned}
$$
Now integrating and dividing yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{ t} \int_{ 0}^{t } ( 2 - x) ^{ n}\, dx  = \frac{1}{ t} \sum_{ k = 0}^{ n} \binom{ n}{ k} ( -1) ^{ k} \frac{ t ^{ k + 1}}{ k + 1} 2^{ n - k}
= \sum_{ k = 0}^{ n} \binom{ n}{ k}  \frac{ ( -1) ^{ k}}{ k + 1} t ^{ k } 2^{ n - k}
.\end{aligned}
$$

Now
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{ 0}^{ t} ( 2 - x) ^{ n}\, dx 
= \frac{ -( 2 - t) ^{ n + 1} + 2^{ n + 1}}{ n + 1} 
.\end{aligned}
$$
Inserting $ t = 1$ you obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{ 2^{ n + 1}- 1 }{ n + 1} 
\end{aligned}
$$
so taking $ n$th root you get $ 2$ as the limit.